# need to refresh page in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery

I am facing some issues with jquery mobile . 
When I move from my first page to second page it does not show the second page as it should be I need to refresh my page every time. It seems like its missing some CSS classes initially. I don't understand why is this happening.

I am using http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css as CSS

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js

http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js as JS.

On the same page I have this anchor tag

```
<a href="" onClick="showText()">showText</a>
```

showText() Method does not call first time and shows javascript error showText not defined but when I refresh the page it works fine.

Comment: you need to add some more information: are these two separate .html files or is it a multipage, or dynamically generated pages you are talking about? How are you calling the 2nd page? Are you calling changePage programmatically, are you clicking a link? Maybe add some more code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding **showText()**:

You have to understand how JQM is working. In order to enable transitions et al, JQM pulls in and drops pages into the DOM. You start with your first page (sort of your BasePage), which is fully loaded with all .js/.css files and enhanced.

When you load the 2nd page, JQM only grabs what's inside *data-role="page" id="your-2nd-page"* and adds this to the DOM after your first page! All scripts outside this div-tag as well as all .css and .js files in the header of the 2nd page will **NOT** be grabbed by JQM.

So, if your showtext() function is on the 2nd page outside of the page div or in a .js file only used in the 2nd page, it will not be grabbed and injected into the DOM, so your function does not work.

When you refresh your 2nd page, the 2nd page will be your fully enhanced BasePage, so all scripts on the 2nd page will be loaded, **BUT** now all scripts on the first page will not work, if you load the first page.

**Solution:** I'm putting all css/scripts in all pages. That way no matter where the user starts, everything needed is loaded.

Comment: Thanks frequent, It solves half of my problem. I am using header.jsp file and all my css and js files are inside this. what I did I moved my javascript code to my header.jsp file and moved all the css and js file in all the individual pages. Now my javascript is working fine but it still not loading the 2nd page correctly. I am using only one css file for all the pages. Is that the problem? From your previous question these are two different html pages

Comment: one css file is no problem. What do you mean by it's not loading correctly? Is it in the DOM? Does it have a class of .ui-page-active? What exactly isn't working as it should?

Comment: my .css files does not have .ui-page-active class inside it. On second page there is a div tag which has data-role="content" and id="cContainer" and its also add two more attributes to this div tag automatically i.e class="ui-content" and role="main" and also add two more div tag inside my div tag with some css classes. So, when I refresh the page it shows a grey background color thats what I want. It does not show that background color intially when I load the page first time.

Comment: hm. I can only guess - either try adding data-theme="c" to your content div, to specifically tell JQM you want a grey background. You can also check Firebug to see on the "wrong" page, which CSS is setting the background wrong. Maybe you are overriding it somewhere in your CSS. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

It's not a solution but it works for my problem.

By using a form post instead of an anchor link, I managed to prevent the cached page from loading.

```
<!-- <a href="index.php?p=6_2"  data-role="none"><img src="images/large_red_arrow.png" /></a> -->
<form action="index.php?p=6_2" method="post" data-ajax="false">
    <input data-role="none" id="view-button" value="view" name="view" type="image" src="images/large_red_arrow.png" alt="View"/>
</form>
```