# After the initial click I have to click twice to get the button to fire again

Tags: jquery, forms, onsubmit

I'm developing an app with jquery/phonegap. I have a page where you can choose a country. Based on that you will be able to get different lists. But you can also return to this 'settings's page and change the country. when you start, the click fires just like it should. But when you return to the settings and try to change country, you have to click twice. Might be easy to solve? Anyone have any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Arena App</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function ProcessC(){
       console.log('test');
        var input = $('input:radio[name=country]:checked').val();
        if (input =='belgium' ) {
            window.localStorage.setItem("country", "Belgium");
            document.location.href = "listarenas.html";
        } else if (input =='holland') {
            window.localStorage.setItem("country", "Holland");
            document.location.href = "listarenas.html"; }
        else {
            window.localStorage.setItem("country", "all");
            document.location.href = "listarenas.html";
        }
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>

<div data-role="page" id="countryPage">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Choose Country</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
         <form action="" data-ajax="false" id="countryp">
         <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                <legend>Choose a country:</legend>
                <input type="radio" name="country" id="all" value="all" checked="checked">
                <label for="all">All</label>

                <input type="radio" name="country" id="be" value="belgium">
                <label for="be">Belgium</label>

                <input type="radio" name="country" id="nl" value="holland">
                <label for="nl">Holland</label>
            </fieldset>
         </div>
         <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="ProcessC();" />
         </div>
         </form>


    </div>      

</div>


<script src="js/arenalist.js"></script>
<script src="js/arenadetails.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

EDIT1: It seems like the prevent default doesn't work the second time you go to the page. Instead it just reloads the page(and the url becomes `http://localhost/arenaapp/www/index.html?country=holland` , for example, if i click on holland), and that's why it works when you click the second time i guess.

EDIT2:
I'll post the code of the page you arrive from as well here:
listarenas.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>The Arena App</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" /> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" /> 
</head>

<body>

<div id="ListArenasPage" data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
    <a href='index2.html' class='ui-btn-left' data-icon='settings' data-theme="a" >Countries</a>
        <h1>The Arena App</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
         <ul id="arenaList" data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filter arenas..."></ul>
    </div>      

</div>

 <script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
 <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/arenalist.js"></script>
 <script src="js/arenadetails.js"></script> 


</body>

</html>
```

And the JS file arenalist.js:

```
var serviceURL = "http://localhost/arenaapp/services/";

var arenas;

$('#ListArenasPage').on('pageshow', function(event) {
    getarenaList();
});

function getarenaList() {
    var country = window.localStorage.getItem("country");
    $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getarenas.php?id=' + country, function(data) {
        $('#arenaList li').remove();
        arenas = data.items;
        $.each(arenas, function(index, arena) {
            $('#arenaList').append('<li><a href="arenaDetails.html?id=' + arena.id + '">' +
                    '<img src="pics/' + arena.picture + '"/>' +
                    '<h4>' + arena.arenaName + '</h4>' + '<p id="category">Club:' + arena.arenaClub + '</p>' +
                    '<p>Capacity:' + arena.arenaCapacity + '</p>' +
                    '<span class="ui-li-count">' + arena.id + '</span></a></li>');
        });
        $('#arenaList').listview('refresh');
    });
}
```

LAST EDIT: As a last edit I would like to point out, for people with the same problem, that one of the reasons I had such big problems was that as you can see in the first code snippet, I had my script before the data-role="page". And with jquery after the initial page, only the things within the page tag will be executed in the rest of the pages. So code must go in the first index-page(where ever) or in other pages after the data-role"page", because of the jquery architecture.

Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8724964/2466991

Comment: Is it `var input = $('input:radio[name=counrty]:checked').val();` **counrty** or the name is **country** ?

Comment: Not sure if this is the issue, but you may try adding `event.stopPropagation();` after `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: Not sure if it's related, but you misspelled "country" here: `input:radio[name=counrty]:checked`

Comment: Thanks for the replies! that would have caused me trouble later on. But that was not the problem. The event.stopPropagation did not solve it either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should probably not be trying to handle this inside of a `submit` type of action.  Really all you are talking about is executing a button's click handler.  Trying to do it inside of a `form onsubmit` is probably adding unnecessary complexity and potential cross browser issues.

Try changing your submit button into a normal `button` element.  Here is where you would register the click handler.  Remove the handler from the `<form onsubmit="">` tag.

```
<input type="button" value="Go!" onclick="ProcessC();" />
```

I think also at that point you can probably drop the `event.preventDefault()` since you don't really need to prevent the default of a simple button click handler.  The default is exactly what you're doing!

Comment: Thanks! Now it works like before the first time I choose a country. But when I head back there to change the country nothing happens at all on Go!. I'm guessing this is because when the onSubmit was in the form element it refreshed the page. That's why it worked the second time. So I guess I should rephrase the question to, 'it only fires the first time'.

Comment: can you try putting an `alert` or `console.log` at the beginning of `ProcessC`?  I'm curious to find out if the event handler is not being called, or if it executes the handler doesn't do anything (due to some flaw in logic).

Comment: @user2466991 also, did you remove the `preventDefault()` completely?

Comment: Yes I did remove it. But yes, it did not print in console or alert. And it says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: ProcessC is not defined" when I check Dev tools after the second time I try to click. So basically if I arrive to that page from another page that function doesn't work. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Edited my post to add the page you arrive from when it doesn't work. I created another page with just a link to that page. And that did work. So might be something there in the arenalist page.

Comment: Also, when I click the link back to the settings. For a split second I can see a longer url in the address bar before it goes to the correct page. Not enough time to see what though.

Comment: @user2466991 please update your markup for the initial page.  Did you change it to a `button` instead of `submit`? If so, you shouldn't really be reloading the page.

Comment: oh, sorry. Yes now it's updated. And it works once. But when I go back to that page from listarenas.html it does not work. I have to refresh, then it will work again.

Comment: Managed to get it to work now. When I moved the function right before the form in the code it started to work. No idea why though. And I'd rather have code in separate js files. For some reason that doesn't work here though.

Comment: @user2466991 If your issue has been resolved, would you be so kind as to upvote and accept my answer? :)